# Different ways to split 8 people into at least two non-empty groups

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

In how many different ways can you split 8 people into at least two non-empty groups?

My attempt:
Since Bell number of 8 elements set is 4140 and we don't need whole set in one partition, is the answer: 4140 - 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good to me. As long as you have the Bell numbers available, and aren't expected to derive the 8th Bell number yourself.